# How to position a Bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, popover

I'm trying to position a Bootstrap popover for a trigger that sits on the far top-right corner of a 960px wide web page.

Ideally, I'd position it on the bottom and move the arrow with CSS (so the arrow is on the top-right of the popover). Unfortunately the 'placement':'bottom' positioning is not enough, since it will center it below the trigger.

I'm looking for solution that will place the popover statically below and on the left of the trigger.

Comment: It would be helpful to better clarify your question with example code and perhaps an image the represents how you'd like the popover to position relative to the trigger.

Comment: I'm also looking for better control of the popover element. Have not found anything yet.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This works. Tested.

```
.popover {
    top: 71px !important;
    left: 379px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is not the solution 'cause there could be plenty of popovers on a page.

Comment: Then all you need to do is change your selector

Comment: That's an aweful solution - you're hard-coding position values in a popover whose dimensions and position are dynamic. I just tried adding that style in dev tools on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers, and unsurprisingly, it didn't work.

Comment: i like that we can set the styles with jquery and works jsut fine in my case and i jsst added more to the selector to narrow the selection

Comment: A poster below actually has the answer that should probably be the accepted one.   He calls out that `viewport` is how to get this properly positioned.   This allows the container to be bound to a constraint without the need of manually overriding the position (especially to a fixed/set position)

Comment: One more thing for those who try this out; one might want to add data-boundary="window" for the popover element as otherwise the re-positioning is limited by the element's dimensions.

Answer (score 21):

Simply add an attribute to your popover! See [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sydney_o9/66uqd12s/7/) if you're in a hurry.

We want to add an ID or a class to a particular popover so that we may customize it the way we want via CSS.

*Please note that we don't want to customize all popovers! This is terrible idea.*

Here is a simple example - display the popover like this:

[image]

```js
// We add the id 'my-popover'
$("#my-button").popover({
    html : true,
    placement: 'bottom'
}).data('bs.popover').tip().attr('id', 'my-popover');
```

```css
#my-popover {
    left: -169px!important;
}
#my-popover .arrow {
    left: 90%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="my-button" data-toggle="popover">My Button</button>
```

Answer (score 13):

I've created a jQuery plugin that provides 4 additonal placements:
topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight

You just include either the minified js or unminified js and have the matching css (minified vs unminified) in the same folder.

https://github.com/dkleehammer/bootstrap-popover-extra-placements

Comment: You plugin destroys for MVVM libs like knockout because it detaches the element from tbe body

Comment: @Pantera61 : What part of the code should I hack to detect collision between 2 popovers? i.e. when 2 nearby popovers are partially overlapping, I want to change their placement dynamically to be away from each other.

Answer (score 12):

## **Popover's Viewport (Bootstrap v3)**

The best solution that will work for you in all occassions, especially if your website has a fluid width, is to use the **viewport** option of the Bootstrap Popover.

This will make the popover take width inside a selector you have assigned. So if the trigger button is on the right of that container, the bootstrap arrow will also appear on the right while the popover is inside that area.
See [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/qor5scka/13/)

You can also use **padding** if you want some space from the edge of container. If you want no padding just use **viewport: '.container'**

```
$('#popoverButton').popover({
   container: 'body',
   placement: "bottom",
   html: true,   
   viewport: { selector: '.container', padding: 5 },
   content: '<strong>Hello Wooooooooooooooooooooooorld</strong>'
 });
```

in the following html example:

```
<div class="container">
   <button type="button" id="popoverButton">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

and with CSS:

```
.container {
  text-align:right;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

## **Popover's Boundary (Bootstrap v4)**

Similar to viewport, in Bootstrap version 4, popover introduced the new option **boundary**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/#options

Comment: This is definitely the best answer.   Setting `viewport` is the key to solving this issue.  The additional css is personal preference

Comment: do u know how to move the tooltip to the left or right in bootstrap popover using the above code, if so can u please share a js fiddle

Comment: this depends on the container selector you use for viewport. in the above example, if you remove text-align: right from .container then the tooltip will have the other direction

Comment: The viewport option was removed in V4

Comment: I wanted to add this viewport argument as a data-viewport attribute and it doesn't work. It throws this error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {selector: '.container', padding: 6}

Comment: Hello mate, are you sure you use Bootstrap version 3? As said in previous comment, this is removed in bootstrap 4.

Comment: I am also not sure if it works as data attribute. Not all properties do. Haven't tried it myself

Answer (score 7):

I solved this (partially) by adding some lines of code to the bootstrap css library. You will have to modify tooltip.js, tooltip.less, popover.js, and popover.less

in tooltip.js, add this case in the switch statement there

```
case 'bottom-right':
          tp = {top: pos.top + pos.height, left: pos.left + pos.width}
          break
```

in tooltip.less, add these two lines in .tooltip{}

```
&.bottom-right { margin-top:   -2px; }
&.bottom-right .tooltip-arrow { #popoverArrow > .bottom(); }
```

do the same in popover.js and popover.less. Basically, wherever you find code where other positions are mentioned, add your desired position accordingly.

As I mentioned earlier, this solved the problem partially. My problem now is that the little  arrow of the popover does not appear.

**note:** if you want to have the popover in top-left, use top attribute of '.top' and left attribute of '.left'

Answer (score 4):

To bootstrap 3.0.0:

```
.popover{ right:0!important; }
```

And modify too

```
.popover { max-width:WWWpx!important; }
```

where WWW is your correct max-width to show your popover content.

Comment: I don't think this works in general because the popover isn't a child of the trigger element. It will only work if the trigger element is on the right of an relative-positioned container.

Answer (score 3):

I had to make the following changes for the popover to position below with some overlap and to show the arrow correctly.

*js*

```
case 'bottom-right':  
    tp = {top: pos.top + pos.height + 10, left: pos.left + pos.width - 40}  
    break
```

*css*

```
    .popover.bottom-right .arrow {  
      left: 20px; /* MODIFIED */  
      margin-left: -11px;  
      border-top-width: 0;  
      border-bottom-color: #999;  
      border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);  
      top: -11px;  
    }  
    .popover.bottom-right .arrow:after {  
      top: 1px;  
      margin-left: -10px;  
      border-top-width: 0;  
      border-bottom-color: #ffffff;  
    }
```

This can be extended for arrow locations elsewhere .. enjoy!

Comment: The arrow is so small - barely noticeable. How can I make it bigger?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [bootstrap source codes](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tooltip.js#L262), you will notice that position can be modified using margin.

So, first you should change popover template to add own css class to not get in conflict with other popovers:

```
$(".trigger").popover({
  html: true,
  placement: 'bottom',
  trigger: 'click',
  template: '<div class="popover popover--topright" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
});
```

Then using css you can easily shift popover position:

```
.popover.popover--topright {
  /* margin-top: 0px; // Use to change vertical position */
  margin-right: 40px; /* Use to change horizontal position */
}
.popover.popover--topright .arrow {
  left: 88% !important; /* fix arrow position */
}
```

This solution would not influence other popovers you have. Same solution can be used on tooltips as well because popover class inherit from tooltip class.

[Here's a simple jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/zabyhf43/)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Fortunately there is a clean way to do that and it is in the Bootstrap popover / tooltip documentation as well.

```
let mySpecialTooltip = $('#mySpecialTooltip); 
mySpecialTooltip.tooltip({
 container: 'body',
 placement: 'bottom',
 html: true,
 template: '<div class="tooltip your-custom-class" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
});
```

in your css file:-

```
.your-custom-class {
 bottom: your value;
}
```

Make sure to add the template in bootstrap's tooltip documentation and add your custom class name and style it using css

And, that's it. You can find more about this on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need this logic for a responsive behavior.

E.g.

```
placement: 'auto left'
```

Bootstrap 3 has **auto** value for **placement**. [Bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/):

> When "auto" is specified, it will dynamically reorient the tooltip. For example, if placement is "auto left", the tooltip will display to the left when possible, otherwise it will display right.