# No place enough for my popup

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popup which works except that the pointer does not point at the good location:
[image]

It seems to be due to a lack of place. Do you know a workaround ? Is the pointer necessarily at the middle of the popup side ? I don't want to change the placement of the popup (`data-placement="bottom"`).

[>>JSFIDDLE<<](http://jsfiddle.net/stla/d6m5L/3/):

```
<table style="width:300px">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Jill is a kiwi<img src='http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg'>" data-html="true" data-animation="true" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" title="Who is Jill?">Jill</a></td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Advanced popover positioning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12017732/704803

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap popover: advanced positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797912/bootstrap-popover-advanced-positioning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to override the bootstrap CSS; the following seems to work in the context of your Fiddle.

```
td { position: relative; }
.popover.bottom { top: 1.5em!important; width: 300px; } // change this to the width of the parent table, otherwise your popup will be the width of the td it's tied to
.popover.bottom .arrow{ left: 10%; } // dictates how far from the left the arrow appears; alter this value as you see fit
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6m5L/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your css file: `.popover.bottom>.arrow{ left:30px;}` to overwrite the default middle alignment of the arrow

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work anymore if I do this: http://jsfiddle.net/stla/d6m5L/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can also place popover on right side of the link with `data-placement="right"`.

Comment: Of course, I know that. The question is about a workaround without changing the placement.