# AngularJS: UI Bootstrap Popover Placement 'bottom-right'

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap and AngularJS, and I want to have popover with placement 'bottom-right', instead of the normal 'bottom' or 'right'. The picture below shows how I would like it work.

[image]

Anybody know how to do this? I've seen this somewhat addressed for plain old bootstrap, but not ui bootstrap here: [bootstrap popover: advanced positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797912/bootstrap-popover-advanced-positioning)

Comment: Have you tried **popover-placement="bottom right"**?

Comment: Can you tried with custom CSS?

Comment: Please Read this [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)

Comment: @ Mihail Stancescu "bottom right" doesn't work - it causes the popover to be placed wrong, and doesn't have an arrow part at all for me.

Comment: @Maher - have read the ui-bootstrap page, but it only give "top, bottow, left and right" as options for popover-placement

Comment: @Dinesh ML - haven't tried any custom CSS - not sure what to change...

Comment: Try with "bottom-right" here is more info [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/popover/docs)

Comment: @MihailStancescu - I've tried that, but it doesn't give the desired effect. I've created a plnkr using the example code in the docs here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TyQXcGNXfZ5py0n37Mse You can see how it behaves for the 'bottom-right' type positions, which is pretty strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep the value of `popover-placement` to `bottom-right`.
Works in the latest builds.

Answer (score 2):

This feature was added under PR [#4899](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/4899) and will be available in the next release.